# how to use ado.net in NET CORE at MAC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos

Now I Learning NET CORE in MAC Mini, Complete the following steps ：

1. dotnet new -t web
2. dotnet restore
3. dotnet run

and then open the  localhost:5000 is success.
next, I Write a Simple ADO.NET Code ,and run it ,result wrong, the code run in window is success, but in mac is wrong, why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Pao.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ccK.jpg)

Comment: I downvoted because of the images of text in your question. This makes relevant facts unsearchable for future users. Please include the relevant text/code/error messages as text.

Comment: please include your _code_, **not** _screenshots of your code_, else you'll just collect downvotes, instead of getting help from the community.

Answer (score 0):

the code is:

```
      string connstr = "server=111.122.21.156,8080;database=yixiao;uid=yixiao;pwd=jianghe";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        Console.Write("conn success.");
        conn.Close();
```

and now i know, the code is no wrong, and run error is the SQL Server 2008 in Remote, and when connect the SQL Server 2012 is no wrong!!!!